How to Unwrap the Mandelbrot Set?
I am working on a method for visually unwrapping the Mandelbrot Set, where the polar equation for the main cardioid is $$c(\theta) = \frac{e^{i\theta} (2 - e^{i\theta})}{4}$$ To accomplish my goal I'm using a modified version of $c$ that adds the variable $r$ - $$f(\theta,r) = \frac{re^{i\theta} (2 - re^{i\theta})}{4}$$ so that $f(\theta,1) = c(\theta)$. Special cases of $f$ occur when $\theta$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$ since $e^{n\pi i}$ $=1$ for even $n$ and $-1$ for odd $n$. This puts the cusp of the cardioid at $f(0,1)=1/4$ and its 'backside' at $f(\pi ,1)=-\frac{3}{4}$.
Now back to my goal. I'd like to use $f$ as a coordinate system so that $\theta$ is mapped horizontally and $r$ vertically in the image. To do this I need to find, for each $\theta$, the value $t$ such that $|f(\theta,t)|=2$. Then $f(\theta,t)$ would lie on the boundary of the circle defined by an escape radius of 2. The required values of $t$ lie in the range $[2,4]$ since both $f(0,4)$ and $f(\pi,2)$ = $-2$. Then vertically the image would go from $f(\theta,1)$ to $f(\theta,t)$. With the exception of $\theta$ = to an integer multiple of $\pi$, these lines are all curves in the Mandelbrot Set beginning at the boundary of the cardioid. For small enough $\theta$ they curve back across the real axis. And of course they are mapped to straight lines in the image.
I have found an iterative solution to this problem but it is a bit slow for image rendering, so an exact solution would be helpful, particularly a direct one of the form $g(\theta)=t$, should one exist. Here's an image made with my iterative solution to give the general idea.
Mandelbrot Set Unwrapped
Thanks!

Why should this question be closed. It is well written (moreover interesting) question attesting work on the issue ?

A detail : do you have a reason to call a variable "pq" ? It is unusual in Mathematics...

The variable pq is commonly used to describe the bulbs in the Mandelbrot Set. It refers to a rational of the form p/q where the denominator q gives the period of the orbits in the bulb. This, together with the numerator p gives the distance around the main cardioid, beginning at the cusp. A full traversal is made when pq varies over [0, 1].

Welcome to Math.SE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Thanks for your answer.

I think instead of aiming for $r$ s.t. $|f(pq,r)| = 2$, a nice image can be made by ensuring the transformation is conformal (angle-preserving).  if that is an option, see my blog post https://mathr.co.uk/blog/2013-12-16_stretching_cusps.html (but I'm still thinking about how to solve your original problem)

Claude - I did peruse your blog post and it was quite interesting and I may very well come back to it later. However, I was going for more of a big picture linear view of the set. I've thought of 3 basic approaches to that: (1) the one you've helped me with, following the cardioid r values out to the escape boundary, (2) going from the pq attachment point out to the escape boundary using the external angle, and (3) finding the tangent line of the r curve at the pq attachment and following that line out to the escape boundary. I have yet to try the 3rd method.

I think your problem comes down to solving a quartic in $r$ given $\theta$:
$$\begin{aligned}
2^2 &= |f(pq, r)|^2 = \left|\frac{z (2 - z)}{4}\right|^2 = \left|\frac{re^{i\theta}\left(2 - re^{i\theta}\right)}{4}\right|^2 = \frac{re^{i\theta}\left(2 - re^{i\theta}\right)}{4} \cdot \overline{\frac{re^{i\theta}\left(2 - re^{i\theta}\right)}{4}}\\
&= \frac{1}{16} r^2\left(r^2 - 4 \cos(\theta)\,r + 4\right) \\
0 &= r^4 - 4 \cos(\theta)\, r^3 + 4 r^2 - 64
\end{aligned}$$
Using wxMaxima computer algebra system:
Setting $\cos(\theta) = 1$ gives $r = 4$.
Setting $\cos(\theta) = 0$ gives $r = \sqrt{2\sqrt{17}-2} \approx 2.499\ldots$.
Setting $\cos(\theta) = -1$ gives $r = 2$.
A differential equation for $r$ is $$\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}\theta} = \frac{\sin(\theta)\,r^2}{3 \cos(\theta)\,r - r^2 - 2}.$$  Maybe some software libraries can be used to solve this (numerically) more efficiently than the quartic for a collection of nearby $\theta$.

[+1] May I ask how you find the differential equation out of the quartic equation for $r$ ?

Thanks so much, Claude! That does work out nicely. I did a comparative test between the quartic solution you found and the iterative solution that I was using. The test was performed over all simple p/q ratios for q in [1, 1000]. The quartic method performed on average 3.5 times faster and both methods agreed in every case tested. As to the differential equation, my math education topped out with 1st year college calculus and some discrete math so I'd have to do some background work to handle differential equations.

Claude - why did you introduce the square on the first term? I was going in a similar direction but that detail escaped me. Other than the squaring I had gotten as far as your 4th step but had not seen how to turn that into a polynomial. I suspect that my desire to find a function of the form f(theta) -> r was clouding my judgement. :)

@JeanMarie using wxMaxima, I put in the quartic with r as a function of t (in place of theta), then differentiated, then solved for dr/dt via a substitution: r(t)^4 - 4 * cos(t) * r(t)^3 + 4 * r(t)^2 - 64; diff(%, t); subst(x, diff(r(t), t), %); solve(%, x);
